# CKEditor toolbar style

Tags: wysiwyg

I am trying to show the label through css on the [CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) (attached image). The wired thing is that the body of the editor is an iframe were my external stylesheet is loaded so the toolbar is not included.

Any ideas of how to work this out? Thank you

```
[![.cke_button__media_label {
  display: inline !important;
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to modify/change a toolbar icon?

Comment: What is the label for? what does it say or do?